# Как инициализировать массив float, который находится в классе из main()

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, классы, инициализация

```
class A
{
private:
    float arr[6];
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << arr[1];
    }
friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.arr[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    obj.print();
}
```

Так не прокатывает. Как реализовать инициализацию массива вне класса?

Comment: Доступ к закрытому полю должны обеспечивать только методы самого класса и друзья класса.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В таких случаях обычно советуют использовать `std::array`. Их, в отличие от обычных массивов, можно присваивать (ведь то, что вы пытаетесь сделать - это присвоение, а не инициализация).

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  private:
    std::array<float, 6> arr;
  public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << arr[1];
    }
    friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    obj.print();
}
```

Или, если вам очень хочется иметь в классе обычный массив, придется копировать в него элементы по одному. Можно конечно использовать цикл, но мы же цивилизованные программисты. :) Поэтому примерно так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  private:
    float arr[6];
  public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << arr[1];
    }
    friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    A obj;

    auto elems = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    assert(elems.size() == std::size(obj.arr));
    std::copy(elems.begin(), elems.end(), obj.arr);

    obj.print();
}
```

Строчка с `assert` - не обязательная. Это проверка, что вы ввели правильное количество элементов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Интересное извращение - делать `main` другом :)

Словом, *инициализировать* можно только в конструкторе, после чего все уже инициализировано и можно только переприсваивать...

Примерно так:

```
class A
{
    A(initializer_list<float> f)
    {
        copy(f.begin(),f.end(),arr); // Тут надо бы проверять, что нет выхода за границы массива.
                                     // Для простоты не стал этого делать.
    }
private:
    float arr[6];
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << arr[1];
    }
friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    A obj = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // Инициализация
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) obj.arr[i] = i+1;  // Переприсваивание
    obj.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Инициализацию* можно сделать вот так (в других ответах массив остается неинциализированным и потом перезаписывается):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

class A
{
    private: static inline constexpr ::std::size_t s_items_count{6};
    private: float m_arr[s_items_count];

    public: template<typename... x_Items>
    A(x_Items... items): m_arr{items...}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(x_Items) == s_items_count);
    }

    public: void print(void)
    {
        ::std::cout << m_arr[1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};
    obj.print();
    return 0;
}
```